# How to use the Vue component $set to set object in single file component

Tags: vue.js

Following Vue.js tutorial, I read this part here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    userProfile: {
      name: 'Anika'
    }
  }
})
// It was stated in the tutorial that, the below will add to userProfile
// while making sure userProfile still being reactive
vm.$set(vm.userProfile, 'age', 27)
```

Nice, would like to try that `vm.$set` function.

However, my implementation is in a single file component, e.g. something like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  data() {
    return {
        userProfile: {
          name: 'Anika'
        }
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

How would I be able to retrive the **vm** variable above? I have tried the following code but didn't work... With error:

> vm.$set is not a function

```
<script>
let vm = {
  name: 'Test',
  data() {
    return {
       userProfile: {
         name: 'Anika'
       }
    };
  }
}
vm.$set(vm.userProfile, 'age', 27)

export default vm;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use it inside the context of your component, you just

```
this.$set(this.userProfile,....)
```

Comment: Thank you again, this works wonder. Also would like to know if vuejs have document the use of `this` in any part of their documents, so I can read more about it, thanks!

Comment: Vue has an extensive documentation, but namely `this` is kind of left out because it's difficult to explain outside the context of a single file component. You can read about `this.$set`[here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) with examples of the two ways. More about `this` [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example)